# Me podrían decir qué es lo que falla en este algoritmo?

Tags: java

Necesito buscar la posición y el valor mayor de este arreglo pero el algoritmo me falla

> public class MayorArreglo {

```
static BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(System.in));
static PrintStream out = System.out;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int[5]numeros = new int[];
    int posDelMayor = 0;

    out.println("Ingrese los números de arreglo: ");
    int numeros[5] = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

    for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
        if (numeros[i] > numeros[posDelMayor]) {
            posDelMayor = i;
        }
    }
    int mayor = numeros[posDelMayor];
    System.out.println("El número mayor del arreglo es: " + mayor + " y se encuentra en la posición " + posDelMayor);
}
```

}

Comment: Podrías mostrar que te devuelve y que valores les pasas?

Comment: Es que en realidad no me corre nada porque tiene muchos problemas, pero recién aprendo a programar y no entiendo muy bien los arreglos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El código tiene 2 errores de compilación:

**1.** Dará un error de compilación esta línea:

```
int[5]numeros = new int[];
```

La forma correcta sería declararlo de esta manera:

```
int []numeros = new int[5];
```

O también así:

```
int numeros[] = new int[5];
```

**2.** El segundo error de compilación:

```
int numeros[5] = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
```

Si quieres rellenar de datos al vector, lo deberías hacer de esta manera (es decir, con un bucle):

```
for(int i = 0; i != numeros.length; ++i)
    numeros[i] = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
```

El código corregido quedaría de esta forma:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Program
{
    static BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    static PrintStream out = System.out;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        int []numeros = new int[5];
        int posDelMayor = 0;

        out.println("Ingrese los números de arreglo: ");
        for(int i = 0; i != numeros.length; ++i)
            numeros[i] = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) 
        {
            if (numeros[i] > numeros[posDelMayor]) 
                posDelMayor = i;
        }
        int mayor = numeros[posDelMayor];
        System.out.println("El número mayor del arreglo es: " + mayor + " y se encuentra en la posición " + posDelMayor);

    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias MrDave, sus respuestas siempre me ayudan montones! Siempre te tomas mucho tiempo en explicar paso a paso y eso me ha ayudado montones a entender la lógica de los problemas

Comment: Una pregunta, en el caso de que yo quiera sumar dos arreglos y hacer uno nuevo con la suma de esos dos, cómo podría corregir este código? "  numerosC[]= (numerosA.length + numerosB.length
                    );
                out.println("La suma de los dos arreglos es: " + numerosC);

Comment: @SuC Sería algo como esto: `System.out.println("La suma de los dos arreglos es: " + (arreglo1[i] + arreglo2[i]));`. Deberías de crear otra pregunta explicando en detalle cual es la duda que tienes.

Comment: Acabo de hacer lo que me dijiste, y quedo así (el problema es que me suma el total de los dos arreglos y lo que necesito es que me imprima el primer numero del arreglo C como la suma del primer numero del arreglo A y el primer numero del arreglo B): 
        }
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            numerosC[j] = (numerosA[i] + numerosB[i]);
        }
        {

            out.print("La suma de los dos arreglos es: " + numerosC[j] + " ");
        }
        out.println();

Comment: @SuC Te recomiendo que detalles de forma explicita tu duda en otra pregunta, de ese modo, te podré ayudar mejor.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando declaras el array numeros, ¿no lo estás haciendo al revés? ¿No sería así?:

```
int[]numeros = new int[5];
```

Comment: Si hago eso me tira lo siguiente: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - variable numeros is already defined in method main(java.lang.String[])

Comment: Eso es porque le has añadido en la línea `int numeros[5] = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());` el `int`. Una vez que declaras una variable **NO** tienes que volver a poner el tipo de variable que es (`int` en este caso)

Comment: Porque abajo la has vuelto a declarar. Cuando poner abajo int numeros[5] = Integer.parseInt..., lo estás declarando otra vez. Para rellenar la tabla así, tienes que meter el out.println y lo de abajo dentro de un for.

Comment: Gracias Felipe!